# Multiply file upload - input field name and file info processed by php foreach

Tags: php, html, foreach

I try to be more specific, the first try was not that.

I'd like to upload 3 images with php. I need all file data (name, size, tmp_name, type) and also the name of the current input field after form submit.

```
<input type="file" name="thisisaname"...>
<input type="file" name="thisisanothername"...>
<input type="file" name="thethirdname"...>
```

I'd need the ImageInputname in my foreach:

```
foreach($_FILES as $file)
{
$ImageName      = $file['name'];
$ImageSize      = $file['size'];
$TempSrc        = $file['tmp_name'];
$ImageType      = $file['type'];
$ImageInputName = ???
...
}
```

What is the easiest way to get the input name?

Comment: Check the first comment on http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php made 11 years ago :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to upload multiple file upload in php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload all files">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
        if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
            $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
            $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
            $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
            $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
            $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];

            for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "test_uploads/".$name_array[$i])){
                    echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
                } else {
                    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
                }
            }

        }
?>
```

Comment: can you explain what's going on here?